# Bootstrap carousel without active class

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I really need help. Can i use boostrap carousel without use active. I want to use only `.item`. Because I'm using wordpress query to generate post. Carousel is not working well with many generate `.active`. Help me thank.

Comment: Can you please explain what kind of problem you are facing?

Comment: yes I just generate post with php loop in wordpress sir. Then I want to use bootstrap carousel. As you know, bootstrap carousel have active class for first slider. Problem was started, I can't generate post with many active class. I want to add only first child to active class. What's the best solution sir ?